# What would Planck's Radiation Law look like if there were only two modes of oscillation, $n = 0, 1$?

Tags: thermal-radiation

I have an idea that the law (since it's based on average energy, number of modes per volume, and a constant) would be shortened to something that would eliminate the summation terms in average energy.

My problem is I can't seem to make the law both frequency AND temperature dependent if I simplify that way.

For reference, Planck's Law is $I(v,T) = [(2*\pi*h*(v^3))/(c^2)]*[1/(e^{hv/kT}-1)].$

Comment: What have you tried? FWIW, ignoring any zero-point energy, the average energy is $\frac{\hbar\omega_0}{e^{\frac{\hbar\omega_0}{k_bT}}-1}+\frac{\hbar\omega_1}{e^{\frac{\hbar\omega_1}{k_bT}}-1}$, which is both frequency and temperature dependent.